# 401 Unatuhorized("detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided.")

Tags: django, angular, authentication, angularjs-directive, django-rest-framework

i am using djoser's authentication at backend. when i make  a get request at "/account/me/" through post man with content-type and Authorization header i am getting a correct response. But when i try to do same request from my angular client i get **401 Unatuhorized("detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided.")** error.
here is my angular service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {homeUrls} from "../../../utils/urls";
import {Http, RequestOptions, Headers Response} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpHeaders,} from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable()
export class AdsService {
  private headers = new Headers();
  private token: string;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log("token is " , this.token);
    //this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.token });
     this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + this.token);
     this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(this.headers);
    this.getMe();
  }

  getMe(): Promise<any> {
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
      return this.http.get(homeUrls.User, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res=> {
          console.log("user is");
          console.log(res.json());
        });
  }
```

and here is the screenshot of headers window of my network tab. 
[image]

any solutions?

Comment: did you add necessary auth credentials such as token in request headers ?

Comment: It's probably that you did not configure your server properly. The screenshot you showed is for the preflight request, which will not pass custom headers. It's up to your server to respond properly

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yeh i have added those headers as you an see in above code

Comment: @David can you be a tittle specific please? which configurations?

Comment: This was happening in my case as well and the reason is basically missing a front slash at the end of the path in tue front end.Djanho expects this and angular path shud have this before send of request.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a preflight requests, custom headers such as `Authorization` will not be included.

So, if your server expects only authenticated users to perform an OPTIONS requests, then you'll end up always getting 401 errors (since the headers will never be passed)

Now, I don't know django at all,  but from this thread here it looks like a known issue

```
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5616
```

Maybe try the suggested workaround, which is using a custom permission checker instead of using django rest framework's default

Workaround (from above thread)

```
# myapp/permissions.py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class AllowOptionsAuthentication(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return True
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

And in settings.py:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.permissions.AllowOptionsAuthentication',
    )
}
```